# For a TCP session, when is the first time an RTT measurement is sampled?

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory, transport-protocol, layer4, rfc

I am trying to understand the RTO mechanism. I have read RFC 6298, but it does not specify when the first RTT measurement is made.

Consider the following packet exchange

1. Client -----Syn-----> Server
2. Client <---Syn+Ack--- Server
3. Client ---Data+Ack--> Server
4. Client <--Data+Ack--- Server

For the client side, is the first RTT measured after receiving Syn+Ack (#2) or  Data+Ack (#4)?

For the server side, is it measured after receiving Data+Ack (#3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTT is measured when transmitting segments, so there must be data in the sent packet so SYN and SYNACK can't provide a measurement.
The RFC says:

> (5.1) Every time a packet containing data is sent (including a
> retransmission), if the timer is not running, start it running...

So since in your example the client sends the first data then yes #4 acks it and provides a RTT measurement.  Equally the server RTT measurement is made when #4 is acknowledged, a packet that you haven't shown (#5 perhaps)

It's in the first TCP RFC, [RFC 793, TRANSMISSION CONTROL PROTOCOL, Section 3.7 Data Communication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.7) says:

> An Example Retransmission Timeout Procedure
>
> Measure the elapsed time between sending a data octet with a
> particular sequence number and receiving an acknowledgment that
> covers that sequence number (segments sent do not have to match
> segments received).  This measured elapsed time is the Round Trip
> Time (RTT).  Next compute a Smoothed Round Trip Time (SRTT) as:
>
> ```
> SRTT = ( ALPHA * SRTT ) + ((1-ALPHA) * RTT)
> ```
>
> and based on this, compute the retransmission timeout (RTO) as:
>
> ```
> RTO = min[UBOUND,max[LBOUND,(BETA*SRTT)]]
> ```
>
> where UBOUND is an upper bound on the timeout (e.g., 1 minute),
> LBOUND is a lower bound on the timeout (e.g., 1 second), ALPHA is  a
> smoothing factor (e.g., .8 to .9), and BETA is a delay variance
> factor (e.g., 1.3 to 2.0).

I haven't followed this through the updates so there may be better or more explicit references.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but can you provide the reference saying that data must be contained in the segment in order for RTT measurement to be taken.

Comment: Edited to show RFC793 quotation

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Just one more thing I don't quite understand. Why SYN, SYN+ACK, and ACK of SYN packets are not used for measuring RTT?

Comment: @314314314: I guess because if the SYN-ACK lost and server needs retransmit it, then the RTT will be wrong, and there is no way client can differentiate that.